# What does "[take a] hard pass" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

"You want to go to the party with me?"
"No, I'll take a **hard pass**."

What does hard pass mean here?
If the person said "No. I'll take a pass on that."

I looked up some definitions of it, it says on those sites it means to decline a proposal. I was just wondering if you can use hard pass the same way you use pass, like "I'll take a hard pass on that."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a [hard pass](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hard+pass) is slang for saying absolutely no.

I have a harder time finding "take a pass" honestly, but I think this is because the meaning is more commonly phrased "I'll pass."  So my idea is that taking a pass is just saying no, while taking a hard pass is a strong no.

Comment: I've heard (and said) "I'll take a pass." It's just a more embellished way of saying "I'll pass." With "hard pass," though, you really need the "take a ~" construction. Btw, I've also heard it as "hard no" a lot of times, but then you take the personal subject out of the sentence: "That's gonna be a hard no."

Comment: I think the principle is that when you pass, you're saying "Skip me over *and maybe ask me again later*" whereas a hard pass is more like "Skip me *and don't come back to ask again*"

Comment: "Hard pass" means basically "Oh Hell No".  I often hear it when the thing is basically beyond being contemplated.      Would you like to be associated with our organization?   (Organization being, say, Westboro Baptist Church).  Hard pass, bro.

Comment: @WarrenP Excellent example.  XD